How to disable in wordpress the option to automatically change links after setting the parent element
Please help. I am using custom breadcrumbs on my wordpress site. I would like to ask if it is possible to disable the automatic change of links after setting a parent element in a subpage.
At the same time I want to keep the link scheme under SEO so that in the https://validator.schema.org/ tool all parent elements show. Thank you very much in advance for your help.
